# Column Cardinality and Total Number of Rows Are Equal

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have a table with 128'914'635 number of rows. Some columns cardinality (i.e. address, lastname, firstname) is equal to the total number of rows in the table (128'914'635). The queries are really slow on this table and they don't use any indexes when I use this table in a join.

Do you have any thoughts why cardinality is equal to the total number or rows in the table?

- ran Anaylze table
- same table collation also no conversion in explain extended
- force index doesnt work

We have a similar issue described in below question. The only difference is that we have the same collation tables and Explain Extended doesn't show explicit conversion.

[MySQL ignoring index, index cardinality is the same as number of records in the table (?!)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/14863/15356)

Any though why still the indexes are not being used and the Cardinality of the field (Address field) is same as number of table rows?

#### Table definition

```
CREATE TABLE `Datasupplied_Consumer_Final` (
  `AddressID` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IndividualId` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `personfirstname` char(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `personmiddleinitial` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `personlastname` char(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PersonSurnameSuffix` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `persontitleofrespect` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `housenumber` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `predirection` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `streetname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `streetsuffix` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postdirection` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unitdesignator` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unitdesignatornumber` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `primaryaddress` char(47) DEFAULT NULL,
  `secondaryaddress` char(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ZipCode` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Zip_4` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `del_point_check_digit` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `msa` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `countycode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `countyname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `citynameabbr` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cityname` char(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `carrier_route` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `censustract` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `censusblock` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Xaxis` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Yaxis` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Zaxis` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dpv_code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NumberOfSources` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dwellingtype` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `secondaryaddresspresent` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `livingunitid` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RDID` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `areacode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Phone` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estimatedincomecode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `homeownerprobabilitymodel` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lengthofresidence` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lengthofresidencecode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numberofpersonsinlivingunit` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `presenceofchildren` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NumberOfChildren` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge00_02` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge00_02Male` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge00_02Female` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge00_02Unknown` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge03_05` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge03_05Male` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge03_05Female` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge03_05Unknown` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge06_10` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge06_10Male` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge06_10Female` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge06_10Unknown` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge11_15` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge11_15Male` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge11_15Female` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge11_15Unknown` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge16_17` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge16_17Male` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge16_17Female` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrenAge16_17Unknown` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `persongender` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `persondateofbirthyear` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `persondateofbirthmonth` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `persondateofbirthday` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `personexactage` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `personagecode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Males_18_24` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Females_18_24` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Unknowngender_18_24` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Males_25_34` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Females_25_34` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Unknowngender_25_34` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Males_35_44` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Females_35_44` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Unknowngender_35_44` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Males_45_54` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Females_45_54` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Unknowngender_45_54` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Males_55_64` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Females_55_64` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Unknowngender_55_64` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Males_65_74` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Females_65_74` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Unknowngender_65_74` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Males_75_Plus` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Females_75_Plus` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Unknowngender_75_Plus` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `personmaritalstatus` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InferredAge` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occupationgroup` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `personoccupation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ethniccode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `languagecode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ethnicgroup` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `religioncode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hispaniccountrycode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `personeducation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `businessowner` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EthnicConfidenceCode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InferredHouseholdRank` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NumberOfAdults` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GenerationsInHousehold` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PresenceOfCreditCard` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `presenceofgoldorplatinumcreditcard` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PresenceOfPremiumCreditCard` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PresenceOfUpscaleRetailCard` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PresenceOfBankCard` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GasDeptRetailCardHolder` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `americanexpresscard` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreditRating` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `investment` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `investmentstocksecurities` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Networth` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NumberOfLinesOfCredit` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Credit_RangeOfNewCredit` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AmericanExpressGoldPremium` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DiscoverGoldPremium` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DiscoverRegular` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GasolineOrRetailCardGoldPremium` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GASOLINE OR RETAIL CARD REGULAR` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MastercardGoldPremium` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MastercardRegular` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VisaGoldPremium` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VisaRegular` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREDIT CARD INDICATOR` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BANK CARD HOLDER` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GAS/DEPARTMENT/RETAIL CARD HOLDER` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TravelAndEntertainmentCardHolder` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreditCardholderUnknownType` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PREMIUM CARD HOLDER` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UPSCALE (DEPARTMENT STORE) CARD HOLDER` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreditCardUser` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreditCardNewIssue` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BANK CARD - PRESENCE IN HOUSEHOLD` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Investing_Active` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InvestmentsPersonal` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InvestmentsRealEstate` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InvestingFinanceGrouping` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InvestmentsForeign` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InvestmentEstimatedResidentialPropertiesOwned` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AssimilationCodes` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `valuehunter` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opportunityseekers` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `newsandfinancial` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `automotivebuff` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bookreader` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MembershipClub` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `computerowner` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cookingenthusiast` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `do_it_yourselfers` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exerciseenthusiast` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Gardener` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `golfenthusiasts` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `homedecoratingenthusiast` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `outdoorenthusiast` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `outdoorsportslover` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `photography` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `traveler` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pets` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cats` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dogs` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mailresponder` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RespondedtoCatalog` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sweepstakes` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `religiousmagazine` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `malemerchbuyer` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `femalemerchbuyer` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `crafts_hobbmerchbuyer` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gardening_farmingbuyer` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bookbuyer` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `collect_specialfoodsbuyer` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `religiouscontributor` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `politicalcontributor` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `health_institutioncontributor` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `charitable` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `generalcontributor` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `donatestoenvironmentalcauses` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `donatesbymail` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `veteraninhousehold` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HeavyBusinessTravelers` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hightechleader` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Smoker` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MailOrderBuyer` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `OnlinePurchasingIndicator` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ApparelWomens` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ApparelWomensPetite` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ApparelWomensPlusSizes` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `YoungWomensApparel` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ApparelMens` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ApparelMensBigAndTall` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `YoungMensApparel` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ApparelChildrens` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HealthAndBeauty` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `BeautyCosmetics` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Jewelry` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Luggage` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMUNITY INVOLVEMENT - CAUSES SUPPORTED FINANCIALLY` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AnimalWelfareCharitableDonation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ArtsOrCulturalCharitableDonation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrensCharitableDonation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ENVIRONMENT OR WILDLIFE  CHARITABLE DONATION` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EnvironmentalIssuesCharitableDonation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `InternationalAidCharitableDonation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PoliticalCharitableDonation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PoliticalConservativeCharitableDonation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PoliticalLiberalCharitableDonation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VeteransCharitableDonation` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CharitableDonations_Other` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CommunityCharities` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Parenting` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SingleParent` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrensApparelInfantsAndToddlers` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrensLearningAndActivityToys` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrensProductsGeneralBabyCare` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrensProductsGeneralBackToSchool` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrensProductsGeneral` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `YoungAdultInHousehold` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SeniorAdultInHousehold` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChildrensInterests` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Grandchildren` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChristianFamilies` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Equestrian` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `consumer_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `ind_personlastname` (`personlastname`),
  KEY `ind_personfirstname` (`personfirstname`),
  KEY `ind_primaryaddress` (`primaryaddress`),
  KEY `ind_state` (`state`),
  KEY `ind_zipcode` (`ZipCode`),
  KEY `ind_city` (`cityname`),
  KEY `ind_estimatedincomecode` (`estimatedincomecode`),
  KEY `ind_personmaritalstatus` (`personmaritalstatus`),
  KEY `ind_persongender` (`persongender`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=43456212 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 <br>
```

and...

```
CREATE TABLE `master_consumer_export_06172013_FullMatchBack_Final` (
  `reg_source` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_addDate` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_firstName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_lastName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_add1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_state` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_zip` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_phone` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_optinUrlClean` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_IPClean` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_dateTime` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reg_dateStandard` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duplicate` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeliveryLine1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeliveryLine2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ZIPCode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FullZIPCode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Latitude` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Longitude` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Precision` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DeliveryPointBarcode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CarrierRoute` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CountyFIPS` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CountyName` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CongressionalDistrict` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Deliverable` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RecordType` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `RDI` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CMRA` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `processingDate` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `suppressed_by_master_suppression` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `master_consumer_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quickiesuppressioncode` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmailUploadedOnQuickie` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MC` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IsBadEMail` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Domain_From_Email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fgx_rdi` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Fgx_Email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `ind_9090909` (`reg_email`),
  KEY `ind_90909address` (`reg_add1`),
  KEY `ind_999900_0090_I` (`DeliveryLine1`),
  KEY `ind_9090909999` (`state`),
  KEY `ind_9090909999Ti` (`city`),
  KEY `ind_9987comb` (`DeliveryLine1`,`reg_lastName`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

now below is the Explain Extended

```
EXPLAIN EXTENDED 
UPDATE Datasupplied_Consumer_Final a,master_consumer_export_06172013_FullMatchBack_Final b
SET a.consumer_email = b.reg_email
WHERE a.primaryaddress=b.DeliveryLine1
AND a.personlastname=b.reg_lastname
AND LEFT(a.personfirstname,1) = LEFT(b.reg_firstname,1)
AND a.cityname=b.city
AND a.state =b.state
AND IFNULL(b.DeliveryLine1,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(a.primaryaddress,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(b.reg_email,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(a.personfirstname,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(b.reg_firstname,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(a.personlastname,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(b.reg_lastname,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(a.cityname,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(b.city,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(a.state,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(b.state,'')<>''  

+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+----------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                                                  | key               | key_len | ref                        | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+----------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ALL  | ind_personlastname,ind_primaryaddress,ind_state,ind_city       | NULL              | NULL    | NULL                       | 37751230 |   100.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ref  | ind_999900_0090_I,ind_9090909999,ind_9090909999Ti,ind_9987comb | ind_999900_0090_I | 103     | load_file.a.primaryaddress |        1 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+---------+----------------------------+----------+----------+-------------+
```

Show indexes from both tables

```
mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM Datasupplied_Consumer_Final;
+-----------------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                       | Non_unique | Key_name                | Seq_in_index | Column_name         | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Datasupplied_Consumer_Final |          0 | PRIMARY                 |            1 | ID                  | A         |    37751230 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| Datasupplied_Consumer_Final |          1 | ind_personlastname      |            1 | personlastname      | A         |     1451970 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Datasupplied_Consumer_Final |          1 | ind_personfirstname     |            1 | personfirstname     | A         |     1797677 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Datasupplied_Consumer_Final |          1 | ind_primaryaddress      |            1 | primaryaddress      | A         |    37751230 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Datasupplied_Consumer_Final |          1 | ind_state               |            1 | state               | A         |       42899 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Datasupplied_Consumer_Final |          1 | ind_zipcode             |            1 | ZipCode             | A         |      129729 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Datasupplied_Consumer_Final |          1 | ind_city                |            1 | cityname            | A         |      243556 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Datasupplied_Consumer_Final |          1 | ind_estimatedincomecode |            1 | estimatedincomecode | A         |       28005 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Datasupplied_Consumer_Final |          1 | ind_personmaritalstatus |            1 | personmaritalstatus | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| Datasupplied_Consumer_Final |          1 | ind_persongender        |            1 | persongender        | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+  

mysql> SHOW INDEXES FROM master_consumer_export_06172013_FullMatchBack_Final;
+-----------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                                               | Non_unique | Key_name          | Seq_in_index | Column_name   | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| master_consumer_export_06172013_FullMatchBack_Final |          1 | ind_9090909       |            1 | reg_email     | A         |   128914635 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| master_consumer_export_06172013_FullMatchBack_Final |          1 | ind_90909address  |            1 | reg_add1      | A         |   128914635 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| master_consumer_export_06172013_FullMatchBack_Final |          1 | ind_999900_0090_I |            1 | DeliveryLine1 | A         |   128914635 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| master_consumer_export_06172013_FullMatchBack_Final |          1 | ind_9090909999    |            1 | state         | A         |       74819 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| master_consumer_export_06172013_FullMatchBack_Final |          1 | ind_9090909999Ti  |            1 | city          | A         |     4604094 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| master_consumer_export_06172013_FullMatchBack_Final |          1 | ind_9987comb      |            1 | DeliveryLine1 | A         |   128914635 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| master_consumer_export_06172013_FullMatchBack_Final |          1 | ind_9987comb      |            2 | reg_lastName  | A         |   128914635 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------------------------------------------+------------+-------------------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: *"some columns cardinality (i.e. address,lastname,firstname) is equal to the total number of rows in a table (128914635),"* what does that even mean?

Comment: What is the definition of column cardinality in MySQL? In other DBMS I've seen it is the distinct number of values, and if the same definition is used here it means that there are 128'914'635 distinct lastname in the table. Not impossible, but rather unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

`DROP INDEX ind_999900_0090_I;`, as it seems to be in the way of using the better (composite) index.

While you are at it, replace the index on primaryaddress with `INDEX(primaryaddress, personlastname)` to see if it will start with the other table.

Since these are huge tables, and there is essentially nothing in the `WHERE` clause to prevent a table scan, you might want to split the query into chunks.  See [*my discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) on chunking.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an indexable condition under any planner I know of.

```
AND IFNULL(b.DeliveryLine1,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(a.primaryaddress,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(b.reg_email,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(a.personfirstname,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(b.reg_firstname,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(a.personlastname,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(b.reg_lastname,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(a.cityname,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(b.city,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(a.state,'')<>''
AND IFNULL(b.state,'')<>''
```

You don't want this,

```
AND IFNULL(b.DeliveryLine1,'')<>''
```

Instead, use

```
b.DeliveryLine1 IS NOT NULL AND b.DeliveryLine1 <> '';
```

That will use an index. Or even better, add a `CHECK` on the column where the value does not permit `''` and update all of the values where `col = ''` setting them to `NULL`;